# How to define a function with multiple clauses and optional parameters in elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to understand how to properly define a function with multiple clauses and optional parameters. When I write

```
  def sum([], total \\ 0), do: total
  def sum([h|t], total), do: h + sum(t, total)
```

(question [Elixir default parameters for named functions with multiple clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080713/elixir-default-parameters-for-named-functions-with-multiple-clauses))

I get the warning:

```
warning: def sum/2 has multiple clauses and also declares default values. 
In such cases, the default values should be defined in a header. Instead of:

    def foo(:first_clause, b \\ :default) do ... end
    def foo(:second_clause, b) do ... end

one should write:

    def foo(a, b \\ :default)
    def foo(:first_clause, b) do ... end
    def foo(:second_clause, b) do ... end
```

I feel like the definition of `sum` follows this recommendation.

Could anyone explain why this is happening and what is the right way to define `sum` and eliminate the warning.

My version of elixir is 1.12.2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare a head clause without `do` block with defaults

```elxiir
def sum(list, total \\ 0) # ⇐ THIS

def sum([], total), do: total
def sum([h | t], total), do: h + sum(t, total)
```

Comment: Just for reference, here is the [documentation for default arguments](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#def/2-default-arguments) which documents this use case.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes: it was  "just" a matter of reading the warning and the doc properly!

Comment: @mszmurlo always welcome, this occasional blindness happens to all of us.